# Delete specific text from filed with or without a space

Tags: mysql

I have field :

`word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6`.

I can add new word like :
`UPDATE mytable SET val=CONCAT(val, 'word7 ')`.

And then I can delete any word :
`UPDATE mytable SET val=REPLACE(val, 'word1 ', '')`.

But it will be ok until somebody manually edits field through phpmyadmin. Because they insert words without space in the end of the field and my program can't delete last word because it hasn't leading space. How can I rid of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick (and lazy) approach would be breaking deletion into two steps:

1. `UPDATE mytable SET val = REPLACE(val, 'word1', '') WHERE val LIKE '%word1%';` -- here you just get rid of the word but leave the spaces. This will work the same regardless of whether the word has a trailing space or not. Note the WHERE condition that only touches rows that contain this text (sometimes this sort of condition can hugely improve query performance; other times it's irrelevant; here I'm guessing it's good to have there).
2. `UPDATE mytable SET val = REPLACE(val, '  ', ' ') WHERE val LIKE '%  %';` -- here you "collapse" redundant spaces if there are any.
3. Leave your `UPDATE` query as-is.

A more farsighted answer would be something along the lines of "You should be using a programming language and/or framework to manage any important MySQL data; why are you doing this by hand? And why is *anyone* editing your data directly in PHPMyAdmin?" That may or may not be helpful input given the constraints of your project, but any modern web development framework will have strong support for managing database updates in a more structured way that eliminates the need for most manual tomfoolery of this sort.

**EDIT:**

It sounds like you're running into the limits of storing "tags" in this way. (Your field may not be tags per se, but it sounds like you need to *treat* them as tags: each word is its own "unit" that can be added and removed as such.

In short, storing them in a long string like this is not ideal for many reasons. You may be limited in your options and be unable to move to a different structure. But if you could restructured it, I would consider **creating a separate `tags` table that contains three fields:**

- `id`,
- `attached_to_object_id` (or `user_id` or whatever; this is the foreign key that points to the parent object this tag is added to), and
- `name` (the actual text for this tag, like `word1`).

To add a tag to an object, the query would look something like:

```
INSERT INTO tags (user_id, name) VALUES ('<the parent object id>', 'word1');
```

And removing a tag from an object would look like:

```
DELETE FROM tags WHERE user_id = <parent object id> AND name = 'word1';
```

If you **can't** change the storage format, I'd definitely impose more structured rules around how tags are delimited. Specifically, I'd impose a rule that any addition / removal from this field must follow the pattern of `[TAG][SINGLE SPACE][repeat...]`. If you *can't* count on other users to maintain this format, then you really shouldn't be letting them touch the database directly; you should set up some sort of interface in another programming language that mediates all additions & removals.

Comment: Good idea but i get problem when i want to delete word1 it also delete other words which consist word1.

Comment: Ah now you're getting into the reasons why this structure isn't a good idea. I've edited my answer to recommend a more ideal structure.

Comment: Thanks for advice. More structured rules can really solve problem. And about fisrt variant i think it's not my case because there are about 20-30k words which are taken fully after each request and i need just these words without other information associated with them.